# Is there a logarithmic scale setting for mplfinance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts, mplfinance

This is the code I am using to plot stock price charts with mplfinance and I would like the graph to be log scaled. How can I accomplish this?

```
import mplfinance as mpf

# Data reading and processing steps omitted

mpf.plot(data, type='line')
```

Comment: what do you get when do `ax = mpf.plot(data, type='line'); print(ax)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `None`

Comment: That's pretty bad API, they could have return either the `fig` or `ax` instance they draw on.

Comment: After importing `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, call `ax = plt.gca()`. Now you should be able to set `ax.set_yscale('log')`. Does this work? I cannot check since you did not provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Timo No, I'm not using matplotlib directly, it's just the library that mplfinance is built with

Comment: Have you tried it? Alternatively you have to alter `mpf.plot()` locally such that it returns a `fig` or `ax` instance.

Comment: @QuangHoang - as you can see from the answer below, the Figure and all Axes objects are returned if you request it.  By default, you don't need it for most use-cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data reading and processing steps omitted

fig, axlist = mpf.plot(data, type='line', returnfig=True)
ax = axlist[0]
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Anyone who would like to add this code to mplfinance, by creating kwarg `yscale=` for method `mpf.plot()`, please feel free to **fork/clone** [**the repository**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) and submit a PR for the change.  The code would then become simply:  `mpf.plot(data, type='line', yscale='log')`

Answer (score 2):

@JakeBoggs worked, but then the text formatting was scientific notation. For anybody else who is looking into this, I would recommend converting the axis back using a ScalarFormatter

```
import mplfinance as mpf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

# Data reading and processing steps omitted

fig, axlist = mpf.plot(data, type='line', returnfig=True)
ax = axlist[0]
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```